# Reverse a string within a list and further reverse the list within a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a multidimensional list which is basically a list of strings nested within a list. I want a list to be reversed and also the list items within the list to be reverse and further the strings in the list should also be reversed.

Ex: I have a list

```
[
    ['123', '456', '789'], 
    ['234', '567', '890'], 
    ['345', '678', '901']
]
```

I want the result to be

```
[
    ['109', '876', '543'],
    ['098', '765', '432'],
    ['987', '654', '321']
]
```

I've already tried the code, It's working. But can we simplify further using list comprehension.

Below is the code which I tried.

```
old = [['123', '456', '789'], ['234', '567', '890'], ['345', '678', '901']]
new = [];
for x in old[::-1]:
    z = [];
    for y in x:
        z.insert(0, y[::-1])
    new.append(z)
print(new)
```

**Input**

```
[['123', '456', '789'], ['234', '567', '890'], ['345', '678', '901']]
```

**Output**

```
[['109', '876', '543'], ['098', '765', '432'], ['987', '654', '321']]
```

Comment: you don't need the semicolons at the ends of the line :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you want this one-liner:

```
result = [[x[::-1] for x in reversed(y)] for y in reversed(lst)]
```

notes:

- `reversed(lst)` is faster than `lst[::-1]` because it doesn't create a new list, it just iterates backwards (in that case it works because the length is known).
- `x[::-1]` is left as-is because it's much faster than `"".join(reversed(x))` to reverse a string as a string.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to modify it after your solution `result = [[x[::-1] for x in y[::-1]] for y in lst[::-1]]`

Comment: yeah works too, but `reversed` is better `[::-1]` creates a new list (allocation, copy...) that you don't need.